# Taking information from two data frame to create a new one in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am working on a text mining project. I am facing difficulties with my dataset. I have two data frame and I need to link the text with the good variables, but I absolutely don't know how to take the text from the first data frame and link it with the second data frame. Can you please help me?

```
First data frame name: reviews

  Text     Newcol          
1   blue    text1
2   green   text2       
3   black   text3      
4   red     text4     
5   yellow  text5         
6   orange  text6
...

Second data frame name: V1
    V1      V2    ...  V801    
1   text3  text1       text5
2   text5  text2       text4
3   text6  text3       text2
4   text4  text4       text1
5   text2  text5       text6  
6   text1  text6       text3

Data frame that I want to create: 

V1   black  yellow orange  red  green  blue
V2   blue   green  black   red  yellow orange
...
V801 yellow red    green   blue orange black
```

---

### Data in `dput` format

```
reviews <-
structure(list(ReqSummary = c("Why don?t the products that are in your promotions show what each product description is for and how it is to be used? This would be so helpful and it may give customers a chance to buy more products that they didn?t think of before. ", 
"Hope this email finds you well.\nWe've been browsing through your website and were wondering if you have any eco-friendly or biodegradable soap for sensitive and acne-prone skin? We live in NYC and are really concerned about the environment and also we have kind off \"demanding\" skin type.\n\nIf you have those types of soap, could you please send us some samples so we can see their quality, texture, smell and size?\n\nIf you are so kind, please send us a sample.\n\nThank you for your time in advance and help!  ", 
"do you still carry eau de cade for men?", "Hello customer care,\n. I had a customer come into my store and inquiry about an E-Gift Card.\nShe stated they she never received her E-Gift Card. I did tell her since an E-Gift Card is purchased online we instore do not have access to her online purchases. I did tell I would out to customer care and provide her info and ask for assistance.\n. She did provide us with the reference .\nIf someone from customer care could please reach out to her via phone and email I would appreciate it so my hands are tied.\n", 
"Hi, \n\nI recently bought Cocon‚ Relaxing Bath Salts. I wonder how much of salt to put into a bath each time. Thanks!\n\nBest,\n", 
"Hello,\nI received a notice that my auto replenish was canceled for some\nreason. When i tried to reactivate it, the site would not allow me to\nclick \"Reactivate.\" Could you please look into this for me. I just had\nto re-purchase the deodorant stick and pay full priced and shipping,\nwhich I did not have to pay before.\nThanks,\n"
)), Newcol = c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6"), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

V1 <-
data.frame(
V1 = c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5")
)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(head(reviews))` and of `dput(head(V1[1:3]))` for us have a data sample in copy&paste format.

Comment: Please also included expected outcome in respect of given dput??

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want: you `lapply` the `match` function to the dataframe, `df2`here, in which you want to replace the `text...`values with the color names from `df1`:

```
lapply(df2, function(x) df1$Text[match(x, df1$Newcol)])
$V1
 [1] "blue"  "black" "green" "black" "black" "blue"  "green" "black" "green" "green"

$V2
 [1] "black" "green" "black" "green" "blue"  "black" "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "black"

$V3
 [1] "black" "black" "green" "black" "green" "black" "green" "green" "blue"  "blue"
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Text  = c("blue","green","black"),
  Newcol = c("text1","text2","text3"))

set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(
  V1 = sample(c("text1","text2","text3"), 10, replace = T),
  V2 = sample(c("text1","text2","text3"), 10, replace = T),
  V3 = sample(c("text1","text2","text3"), 10, replace = T)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I am having a list. Is it normal because I need a data frame.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the data you have posted, as `dput(head(reviews))`shows a different structure than the dataframes decribed in the beginning of the question; for example, the column `Text` is missing and the column `ReqSummary`contains running text instead of single words. Can you provide some clarification here?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was allowed to share the dataset, but I clarified the situation so I updated a small sample of my data set. In fact the name of the column is not Text but ReqSummary and we have text and not single words.

Comment: This only clarifies the task a little. What about the color names? I can't see any in `ReqSummary`?!

Comment: It's just an example that I used to make it easier (which I failed ahahah) to understand the steps that I have to do with my data. They are not included in my data set. I need the same output as the example that I gave with the color but with the reviews and V1 data frame

Comment: I think you should thoroughly rework your question so that ppl have a better chance to help you. Put yourself more in the position of the reader of your post: which info must they get to properly understand your issue and which data do they need to be able to help you with it?

Comment: @Narin, I am of same views those of Chris's that you need a thorough revision of the question you'd put up.  Your example says something else and dput states some other story

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `match` way.

```
res <- lapply(V1, function(x){
  NewCol <- attr(reviews, "Newcol")
  i <- match(NewCol, x)
  reviews$ReqSummary[i]
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
res <- as.data.frame(res)
names(res) <- paste("Col", seq_len(ncol(res)), sep = "_")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it's not working on my case. I have more than 5 column and my observations are full of NA

Comment: @Narin Done, see the edit.

Answer (score -2):

Finally found an answer:

```
new_frame<-lapply(V1, function(x) reviews$ReqSummary[match(x, reviews$Newcol)])
ndf<- as.data.frame(new_frame)
names(ndf) <- paste("Col", seq_len(ncol(ndf)), sep = "_")
final<-matrix(ndf, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
```